# Hacer 2 o mas PIVOT a una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Tengo una tabla que es basicamente esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero hacer pivot para que quede de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he logrado por ningun medio hacerlo, utilice este codigo:

```
  SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT PROVISION_EXPLOTACION, SERVICIO, NORESUELTA_INSAT, NORESUELTA_COMENTARIO
  FROM TABLA_1
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(NORESUELTA_INSAT)
  FOR SERVICIO IN ([G Suite], [MacroLAN], [VPN IP], [IBERCOM IP])
) AS pvt1
```

pero solo me arroja esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo lograr el resultado que busco?

Answer (score 0):

El escenario que indicas.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA_1
             (
             PROVISION_EXPLOTACION VARCHAR(100)
           , SERVICIO_GRUPO        VARCHAR(100)
           , SERVICIO              VARCHAR(100)
           , NORESUELTA_INSAT      INT
           , NORESUELTA_COMENTARIO INT
             );

INSERT INTO TABLA_1(PROVISION_EXPLOTACION
                  , SERVICIO_GRUPO
                  , SERVICIO
                  , NORESUELTA_INSAT
                  , NORESUELTA_COMENTARIO)
VALUES
       ( 'PROVISION',   'CLOUD', 'G Suite'              , 23, 13 ),
       ( 'EXPLOTACION', 'DATOS', 'MacroLAN'             , 45, 14 ),
       ( 'PROVISION',   'VOZ',   'VPN IP'               , 18, 66 ),
       ( 'EXPLOTACION', 'GPT',   'IBERCOMP IP CENTREX'  , 11, 25 );
```

Dado que das muy pocos datos, para poder pensar en soluciones, una opción viable parece, utilizar una cte correlativa, y hacer dos pivots diferentes. Luego usar union All para unir la salida de ambos.

```
WITH DATA1 AS (
SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT 'NORESUELTA_INSAT' AS DATA
                   , TABLA_1.SERVICIO
                   , TABLA_1.NORESUELTA_INSAT
                     FROM TABLA_1
            ) AS SOURCE 
PIVOT (MAX(NORESUELTA_INSAT) FOR SERVICIO IN([G Suite], [MacroLAN], [VPN IP], [IBERCOMP IP CENTREX]))PVT 
), DATA2 AS (
SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT 'NORESUELTA_COMENTARIO' AS DATA
                   , TABLA_1.SERVICIO
                   , TABLA_1.NORESUELTA_COMENTARIO
                     FROM TABLA_1
            ) AS SOURCE 
PIVOT (MAX(NORESUELTA_COMENTARIO) FOR SERVICIO IN([G Suite], [MacroLAN], [VPN IP], [IBERCOMP IP CENTREX]))PVT 
)   
SELECT * FROM DATA1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM DATA2;
```

[image: Res1]